# Callback query handler в боте на aiogram не запускается

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

Есть функция:

```
async def create_bill(message:types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.isdigit():
        amount = int(message.text)
        await message.answer('Создаю счет для оплаты...')
        logging.logger_info.info('Создается счет')
        bill = p2p.bill(bill_id=message.from_user.id+1, amount=amount, lifetime=5)
        payment_url = p2p.check(bill_id=message.from_user.id+1).pay_url
        pkb_btn_1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Оплатить', url=payment_url)
        pkb_btn_2 = (InlineKeyboardButton(text="Зачислить на счет", callback_data='update'))
        pkb_mark_1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup.add(pkb_btn_1)
        pkb_full = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2).add(pkb_btn_1)
        pkb_full.add(pkb_btn_2)
        logging.logger_info.info(f'Создан счет #{bill.bill_id} на сумму {amount} для пользователя {message.from_user.id}')
        await message.answer('Счет создан!\nНажмите на кнопку, чтобы оплатить', reply_markup=pkb_full)
        await UserStates.next()
    else:
        await message.answer('Пожалуйста, введите число!')
        logging.logger_info.info(f'Пользователь {message.from_user.id} ввел некорректные данные')
```

Она работает и выдает клавиатуру с двумя кнопками. Первая кнопка - просто ссылка (она работает), вторая должна вызывать следующий хэндлер:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == 'update')
async def process_callback_balance_update(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state=UserStates.waiting_for_payment):
    if user.get_user_block_status(callback_query.from_user.id):
        await callback_query.message.answer('Вы были заблокированы')
        logging.logger_warn.warning(f'Заблокированный пользователь {callback_query.from_user.id} пытался подключиться к боту!')
    else:
        if p2p.check(bill_id=callback_query.from_user.id+1).status != 'PAID':
            await callback_query.message.answer(text='Оплата не прошла!')
            logging.logger_warn.warning(f'Пользователь {callback_query.from_user.id} пытался пополнить баланс с неоплаченным счетом!')
        else:
            current_balance = user.get_user_balance(callback_query.from_user.id)
            new_balance = current_balance + float(p2p.check(bill_id=callback_query.from_user.id+1).amount)
            logging.logger_info.info(f'Производится зачисление средств на баланс пользователя {callback_query.from_user.id}')
            user.change_user_balance(callback_query.from_user.id, new_balance)
            await callback_query.message.answer(text='Деньги зачислены')
            await state.finish()
            logging.logger_info.info(f'Деньги зачислены. Баланс пользователя {new_balance}')
```

Но хэндлер не вызывается! Я пыталась менять/убирать состояние, указывать text вместо data в декораторе, переставлять этот хэндлер в ранзые места кода - ничего
В логах это:

```
aiogram.contrib.middlewares.logging - INFO - Unhandled callback query [ID:1342058245786784398] from user [ID:312472285] for message [ID:621] in chat [private:312472285] with data: users originally posted by user [ID:5621517130]
```

Но такое же сообщение появляется при вызове другого хэндлера, написанного аналогично и полностью рабочего

Comment: У вас две функции с таким @dp.callback_query_handler декоратором?

Comment: Так вы же не указали стейт в колбек хендлере. Добавьте его

Comment: Пока две, в итоге должно быть 6

Comment: Пробовала указывать стейт (и конкретный и ‘*’ - не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в строке:

```
await UserStates.next()
```

Нужно было заменить на state.finish() и не указывать state в хэндлере